# Defining not_equal Function in Python

Tags: python, function, return, nonetype

So the assignment is to imagine that python does not have != built in, and to write a function not_equal that takes two parameters and gives the same result as the != operator.

I've written he following code:

```
def not_equal(x, y):
     if x == 0 or y == 0: #avoid error message for dividing by 0
         if ((y+1)/(x+1)) == 1:
             equal = False
     elif x/y == 1:
         equal = False
     else:
         equal = True
     return equal
```

and tested the following test cases:

```
print not_equal(3, 4)
print not_equal(5, 5)
print not_equal(0, 3)
print not_equal(4, 0)
```

The first two work, but the second two give me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dvanderknaap/Desktop/My Python Programs/hw2.py", line 73, in <module>
    print not_equal(0, 3)
  File "/Users/dvanderknaap/Desktop/My Python Programs/hw2.py", line 67, in not_equal
    return equal
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'equal' referenced before assignment
```

Why?

Comment: Take a look at the nested if and insert your numbers there and check what they produce.

Comment: Think about x=-1, y=0.

Comment: Also, be careful here -- on python2.x (which it appears that you are using by your print statements), `3/2 == 1  # True`, but `not_equal` will probably say `False` in this case :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you supply a 0 as either x or y, this code is triggered:

```
if x == 0 or y == 0: #avoid error message for dividing by 0
     if ((y+1)/(x+1)) == 1:
         equal = False
```

Now, for (0, 4), Python checks if (4+1)/(0+1) equals 1, and since it doesn't, it never sets `equal` to anything.

Comment: Ahhh, so I added an else condition within this first if loop that if it didn't equal 1, it would return True. Great! Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. :) Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3):

Why do anything so convoluted?!  After all the hypothesis is that `!=` disappears, but I see nothing about `==`, so it should still be there!-)

```
def not_equal(a, b):
    return not (a==b)
```

Comment: That would be too easy.

Comment: @jgritty, some are born simple, some achieve simplicity, and some have simplicity thrust upon them... I belong in the latter group!-)

Comment: I guess OP should explain why the simplest answer is not sufficient.  I assumed there must be some reason they didn't use this approach.

Comment: We were supposed to use conditional statements, sorry for not posting the whole assignment

Comment: @numbersloth, with conditional statements, `if a==b: return True` and of course `else: return False` will work very well too!-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if x == 0 or y == 0: #avoid error message for dividing by 0
         if ((y+1)/(x+1)) == 1:
             equal = False

print not_equal(0, 3)
print not_equal(4, 0)
```

This ones, put them in to your `if` statement;

```
(y+1)/(x+1)= 1/4 and 1/4 != 1.
(y+1)/(x+1)= 5/1 and 5 != 1.
```

So your `if` statement is never process unless x and y = 0 .

Comment: To be fair, the answer provided by @JoelHinz is (IMHO) a lot easier to understand.  When I read his answer I can clearly see the problem, specifically, in some cases `equal` doesn't get set -- In your explanation, It's a lot harder to discern exactly what you're trying to say (even though, ultimately, you are trying to say the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

The error may arise because of an error in declaring the equal variable. Declare the variable `equal` explicitly before using it, i.e. `equal = None`.

Alternatively, here is a function to accomplish the same goal (since `==` is still allowed by your assignment):

```
def not_equal(x, y):
    if x == y:
        equal = False
    else:
        equal = True
    return equal
```